# All of the words, those I use to train the word2vec model, must be in model.vocab, aren't they?

Tags: python, gensim, training-data, word2vec

I use the next code to train the model:

```
norms_train = [ [''], [ u'word', u'to', u'learn', ... ], ...]
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(norms_train, size=100, window=10)
```

With procedure to check the results:

```
i, j = 0, 0
for text in norms_train:
    j += len(text)
    for word in text:
        if word not in model.vocab:
            i += 1
print i, '/', j
```

13129 / 185379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All words that you have used to train the Word2Vec model should be in model.vocab. There may be a threshold on the minimum number of occurrences of a word, that have to be present for it to be included in the model vocabulary.

I suppose the argument `min_count` is set to 5 by default i.e. if a word has occurred less than 5 times in the training data, that word would not be present in the model.vocab.

Comment: Yes, now I see - min_count=5

Comment: Try setting `min_count` = 0 and then training your model again. That might help.